# Start an activity when a particular text is entered in the application

Tags: android

Here is what i need:
I need to start an activity when a particular password is entered or a button is long pressed in the home screen of my app.
I have a registration page where the user can register..
but suppose it is the admin who is using the page he may enter a particular sequence of text and it will take him to that screen..
please not i don't provide any text box for the admin to enter the password..there should be some listener in background which waits for this particular event..
can you guide me on how this can be implemented?

Comment: What have you tried so far ... post some code that you have tried .... then its easier for Stackoverflow community users to help you with a better answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this as

```
EditText userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userName);
userName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
}

public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
 int count, int after) {
}

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
 int before, int count) {
if(s.equals("AdminUser")){
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AdminActivity.class);
}
}
});

}
```

Now As soon as user type "AdminUser" on edittext then it will start move to next activity.
I hope this will help you :) Good luck :)